# I am trying to view webp image in imageview it's size is below 200kb . but it is showing overflow error

Tags: android, webp

I using imageview in android app and i also tried with picasso but it crashed
 i am trying to load it from

```
  ImageView hl=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.homepag);
       Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.s1).into(hl);
```

error

```
 Process: com.va.androidapp, PID: 6920

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too 
large(144000000bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
```

Image details
 [image: webp is showing overflow error in android imageview]

Comment: what is the image resolution and where do you store the image?

Comment: Which folder do you use for storing the image? drawable, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi etc. ?

Comment: I was added in drawable and after moved to xxhdpi it work successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the image into High-res folder and check. drawable-xhdpi like that.